# How can I make this big C# loop faster?

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop

The code under is using one full core performace and it's very slow that it takes 10-12 seconds to finish, how can I make it faster?

```
NetworkStream networkStream = (NetworkStream)param;
byte[] sendBytes = new byte[1000000];
int current = 0;
int cpos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
    {
       for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++)
       {
          sendBytes[current] = i;
          current++;
          sendBytes[current] = j;
          current++;
          sendBytes[current] = k;
          current++;
          for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++)
          {
              for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
              {
                  for (int z = 0; z < 16; z++)
                  {
                      sendBytes[current] = getItem(x + i * 16, y + j * 16, z + k * 16);
                      current++;
                  }
              }
          }
          //Here it also copies the old bytes and compresses them using zlibstream
          networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, current);
          current = 0;
      }
   }
}
byte getItem(int x, int y, int z)
{
   return blockIds[x, y, z];
}
```

Edit: Added the missing method code.

Comment: What's with the loop in a loop in a loop in a loop in a loop?

Comment: What is the *initial problem* (which you try to solve with the deep nested loops), please?

Comment: i, j, k are boxes with items, x y z determines the exact place of item in the box

Comment: The problem is that the code is very slow

Comment: Game with blocks but not minecraft

Comment: Well you're calling `getItem` 16 million times. We don't know what that's doing, which makes it hard to help, but if that's anything other than "really, really fast" then it's unsurprising that it's slow.

Comment: (You could remove 3 multiplications by 16 on each inner iteration by doing those before the loop, and you could remove but I wouldn't be surprised if the JIT was doing that already.)

Comment: Why aren't you just writing `blockIds` directly?

Comment: The received data is incorrect if i write it like that.

Comment: Okay, now that we can see that you're using a rectangular array, that may well be the problem. Those are slow relative to simpler arrays. Are you able to change `blockIds`? There are various options for other ways of representing the data, but we can't help until we know more about what you can and can't change.

Comment: "The received data is incorrect if i write it like that." - Like what? It's unclear which comment you're replying to, or what change you made.

Comment: The client builds up the items, wrong way or not fully. Sometimes throws exceptions that array is out of bounds.

Comment: Does the code always produces same output? If it does, you could cache it, e.g. by storing it on the hard disk.

Comment: It doesn't, there are modifications to the blockIds rectangular array.

Comment: So maybe one of the approaches would be to modify the output when rectangular array gets changed, instead of creating a new output with all those iterations.

Comment: Without changing the data structures, you can already divide the number of iterations by 16 by replacing the last `for (int z = 0; z < 16; z++)` with a single `Buffer.BlockCopy` operation

Comment: That said, all the comments here (including mine) are assuming that `getItem` is the bottleneck. While it seems likely, it could just as well be `networkStream.Write`. You should run a profiler on your code to make sure

Comment: Just explain us in deep what you are trying to do (using English), there must be a better way.

Comment: Send over 16MB data with 15Mbps bandwidth need about 10 seconds, so why are you think it's slow?

Comment: I'm trying to send all boxes (every box is 16x16x16), including all items that are in it and keep the `byte[]` not too big for it to be sent through `networkStream.Write`. Changes are being made to the array (eg. Item destroyed) so i cannot save and send the same thing everytime. I'm trying to make the loop fast enough that it won't take one full core performace and take less than 10 seconds. Note that sending saved thing takes only 0.1 seconds.

Comment: Most important thing to always do is use a profiler to find the bottleneck.  You'll no doubt see that it is not the loops or getItem, it is the networkStream.Write() call that bogs it down.  Too much data to buffer, the receiver can't read it fast enough.  Fixing that requires a major rewrite, send less data by keeping state on both ends and only transmitting the changes.

Comment: Yea, I agree with HansPassant, just like I said, cache the data and send only when rectangular array has changed. No point to send mostly the same data over and over again.

Comment: The data is only sent when client is connecting to load all the boxes on client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that sending saved thing takes only 0.1 seconds

I guess it's the duration for 1 call to `NetworkStream.Write` method

A simple test by sending data to loopback. It costs about 300ms on my PC, and 50ms without sending data. So obviously the reason is the speed of your network.

The loop is **fast enough**

```csharp
//Local server
Socket server = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
Socket peer = null;
server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 29999));
server.Listen(50);
server.BeginAccept(ar =>
{
    peer = server.EndAccept(ar);
    byte[] buf = new byte[16 * 16 * 16 + 3];
    while (peer.Connected)
        peer.Receive(buf);
},
null);

//Client
Socket client = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 29999));
var networkStream = new NetworkStream(client);

//Loop
byte[] sendBytes = new byte[16 * 16 * 16 + 3];
int current = 0;
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++)
        {
            sendBytes[current++] = (byte)i;
            sendBytes[current++] = (byte)j;
            sendBytes[current++] = (byte)k;

            for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
                    for (int z = 0; z < 16; z++)
                        sendBytes[current++] = getItem(x + i * 16, y + j * 16, z + k * 16);

            networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, current);
            current = 0;
        }
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

//Clean works
client.Close();
peer.Close();
server.Close();
```